# loop data attributes and set corresponding input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
  //for each data attr - corresponding input value = data.value
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atitle' data-x='lorem' data-y='ipsum' data-z='dolor'>title</div>
<br>
<input type='text' id='input_x'>
<input type='text' id='input_y'>
<input type='text' id='input_z'>
```

result:
`input_x` has value `lorem`
`input_y` has value `ipsum`
`input_z` has value `dolor`

Comment: what is the relationship between data attributes and input id values?

Comment: data-* and input_* ?

Comment: @TomaszBucko, yes, of course

Comment: and array will be only x, y, z? or more strings?

Comment: @TomaszBucko in reality there is 14 data attributes, so I need a loop

Comment: please check my answer, it's fully independent from attributes keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function() {
  // get data of all data attributes 
  // (it's an object like this { x: "lorem", y: "ipsum", ...)}
  let data = $(this).data();
  // Set data to input values.
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    let elem = $(`#input_${key}`);
    // Check if elem exists before trying to assign a value. 
    // Just in case if .atitle contains some data attributes, 
    // which have no mapping to an input element.
    elem && elem.val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atitle' data-x='lorem' data-y='ipsum' data-z='dolor'>title</div>
<br>
<input type='text' id='input_x'>
<input type='text' id='input_y'>
<input type='text' id='input_z'>
```

Comment: `elem && elem.val(value);` - can you explain, pls. btw I didn't downvote

Comment: @qadenza The second part of the expression is only executed if `elem` is set. It's a short way for `if (elem) elem.val(value)` Check also the comment.

Comment: @qadenza Instead of `elem && elem.val(value);` you could actually also use `elem?.val(value);` But you need to be carefully, since some mobile browsers do not support it yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optionale_Verkettung

Answer (score 1):

you can read this

```js
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
  var title= $(".atitle");
  let arr=title.data();
  console.log(arr)
  $('input').each(function( index ){   
      $( this ).val(arr[this.id.split("_")[1]])
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atitle' data-x='lorem' data-y='ipsum' data-z='dolor'>title</div>
<br>
<input type='text' id='input_x'>
<input type='text' id='input_y'>
<input type='text' id='input_z'>
```

Comment: This won't work, if there are additional or maybe missing inputs or if the order of the input differs.

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at this example

```js
const trigger = document.querySelector(".atitle");

trigger.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(event) {
  const { x, y, z } = Object.assign({}, event.target.dataset);

  document.querySelector("#input_x").value = x;
  document.querySelector("#input_y").value = y;
  document.querySelector("#input_z").value = z;
}
```

```html
<div class="atitle" data-x="lorem" data-y="ipsum" data-z="dolor">title</div>
<br />
<input type="text" id="input_x" />
<input type="text" id="input_y" />
<input type="text" id="input_z" />
```

See

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Why do you want to use `const { x, y, z } = Object.assign({}, event.target.dataset);`. You could just use `const { x, y, z } = event.target.dataset;`

Comment: Nice trick, The answer is because it makes explicit my intention. btw here another way `const {x, y, z} = {... event.target.dataset};`

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code. It's fully independent from keywords of attributes.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.atitle', function(){
  var title= $(".atitle");
  $.each($(title)[0].attributes, function(key, value) {
    var attr_name = value.name
    if (attr_name.indexOf('data-') > -1) {
        var attr_val = value.value
        var attr_idx = attr_name.split('data-')[1]
        $('#input_' + attr_idx).val(attr_val)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='atitle' data-x='lorem' data-y='ipsum' data-z='dolor' data-xx='xlorem' data-yy='yipsum' data-zz='zdolor'>title</div>
<br>
<input type='text' id='input_x'>
<input type='text' id='input_y'>
<input type='text' id='input_z'>
<input type='text' id='input_xx'>
<input type='text' id='input_yy'>
<input type='text' id='input_zz'>
```